# Spring Boot Adding Bearer Token to swagger shows the Authorization (lock symbol), but doesn't give 401 Unauthorized when triggered it without a token

Tags: spring-boot, jwt, swagger, swagger-ui, bearer-token

I have my swagger config file as below,

```
@Configuration
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "BearerAuth",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer"
)

public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(new Info().title("---- API")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .description("This is --- API"));
    }
}
```

And in the controller,

```
@Validated
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "BearerAuth")
public class StudentController {

 @PostMapping("students")
    public ResponseEntity<StudentModel> saveStudent(                                                                    @Valid @RequestBody(required = true) Student student, BindingResult bindingResult) {
...
```

But when I access http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/ it does shows the  lock symbol Infront of the api but when execute the relevant url, I'm not getting 401 unauthorized status when I don't pass the bearer token.

My build.gradle file,

```
implementation('org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.5.3')
```

Comment: did you secure your students endpoint?

Comment: @Aleson I didn't get your question. I configures in class level following the below url baeldung.com/openapi-jwt-authentication

Comment: By the code you provided there is no authorization rule set to your endpoints thats why spring security does not throw any error